# Push Notification in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am new to Ionic development. I have been using Ionic2 for my application and trying to add push notification (FCM) for the last couple of hours. However, I am stuck in adding push configuration. Here are the details:

1. `"phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.0.0"` is configured in my package.json file. Also native push plugin is `"@ionic-native/push": "^4.3.1"`
2. In config.xml, I have added `<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />`. Also added `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0" />`.

   3.Here is the code I am using in my main component file:

   ```
       const options: PushOptions = {
         android: {
           topics: ['topic1']
         },
         ios: {
           alert: 'true',
           badge: true,
           sound: 'false'
         },
         windows: {},
         browser: {
           pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
         }
       };

       const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

       pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
           if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
               let pushAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                   title: 'BrainCal Notification',
                   message: notification.message.title
               });
               pushAlert.present();
           }
       });

       pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
           //do whatever you want with the registration ID
       });

       pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => alert('Error with Push plugin' + error));
   ```

It is deployed successfully in my Android phone. However, it return following error while opening the app first time:

```
"Error with Push plugin no senderID value given".
```

As per my understanding latest phone gap plugin does not require senderID as it uses Google-services.json file. Please advise.

Comment: Try add  `<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0" >
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </plugin>` in `config.xml`

Comment: Already tried without any luck.

Comment: `android: {
        senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",topics: ['topic1']
      }` try this.

Comment: In latest version of push plugin this key ("senderID") is not the part of "interface AndroidPushOptions". So can not use it

Answer (score 0):

remove your plugin `ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push` then install it with parameters like below

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=HERE_YOUR_SENDER_ID
```